# Giving access to S3 bucket to an external user without an IAM account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a requirement where we need to send a data file everyday to one of our clients (They don't belong to our organisation). Usually we recommend SFTP connection for file sharing, however this particular client didn't want to go with SFTP route. They asked us if we could share the files over S3. The client in question do not use AWS cloud, they use Azure. I do not know how they wanted to access the files in our S3 bucket in Azure but I guess they probably are looking to use Azure Data Factory's S3 connection manager (I am not sure how).

Now, I have created a S3 bucket with a generic name and created a folder within the bucket for the specific client. I wrote a AWS CLI command which copies the files from our server (EC2) into S3 folder.

I have no idea how I could give these users access to the s3 folder. I have searched the internet for ideas. What I see is many people suggesting to use PreSigned URL or there are many articles explaining how the access is granted for an IAM user.

From my understanding PreSigned URL is specific for each object within the folder. If I need the client to access a new file everyday, should I create a presigned URL everyday? and how do I share this URL to the client everyday?

The Presigned URL simply downloads the file, but if they want to use the URL in ADF, I do not know if it works that way or not.

Alternatively, if I create a IAM user for this user, and assign a Bucket policy to this IAM User then how would they access the bucket? I mean what should I give them?

I am more confused about the 2nd approach as I am not sure how it works if I want to provide two different clients to two different folders within the same bucket.

Could you please suggest what should I do?

For this particular client, because they use Azure, I could also request them if I can dump the file directly their Azure Data Lake storage (if it is possible to do).

Comment: Azure Data Factory seems to take an AWS Access Key and Secret Key. So, you could create an IAM User for them, and add an IAM Policy to the IAM User to grant access to the desired Amazon S3 bucket. This would be better than creating a Bucket Policy on the bucket. The page linked by @sloppypasta shows the required permissions.

Comment: You are right, I followed your approach created a IAM user for the client. As per @sloppypasta's URL I need to provide them a S3 endpoint URL. Any idea how I could generate it?

Comment: Endpoints are typically of the format `s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` -- see [Amazon Simple Storage Service endpoints and quotas - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Azure is the preferred method, your external users could set up an Azure Data Factory Connection as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-amazon-simple-storage-service?tabs=data-factory). In this situation you will need to provide them with access keys for an IAM user with appropriate permissions in your account. Alternatively, they could use the AWS CLI as it sounds like you have done to access the files. Keys for an appropriately configured IAM user would still need to be shared.

Or, depending on the nature of the data involved, you might be able to just make the bucket publicly accessible, which would simplify the process. In that case, no keys or secrets would be necessary, and anyone who knows the bucket name would be able to access its contents.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @sloppypasta. I didn't want to make the bucket public because of the sensitive data involved. I loved the approach you have suggested but I'd appreciate any pointers to how I could create a endpoint URL for the s3 bucket.

Comment: The current preferred URL format is the virtual-hosted-style and it takes the form of `https://<your_bucket_name>.s3.<region_code>.amazonaws.com/<path_to_file>`. There are other formats but they are either being deprecated or potentially more complicated than what you need. I've never used an Azure Data Factory Connection so I don't know if it will perform the authorization signature calculation for you, but I assume it does. This connection will be more durable than using pre-signed URLs which you would have to update regularly. That could be good, or could be bad, depends on your situation.